# Python, having problem colouring a project for readability

Tags: python, colors

So I have Dictionary that prints exactly what I want it to print:
Eg. `{key:["Argument"]}`
I have been trying to color just the key because I'm going to use it for a sub menu in my shell.
I have tried:

```
Dictionary={}
for i in range(len(List)-1):
    Dictionary[i] = [List[i + 1][0]]
print("\033[31m{}\033[m".format(Dictionary))
```

The print basically renders everything red.
Is there a better way? Can I achieve what I want? Or is it not feasible?

Comment: You need for do a for or key/value pairs, and call your own print on these, changing to red and back to black after the key

Comment: Many thanks on poiting me in the right direction.@B.go

Comment: Thanks for the editing points. But you could just add 4 spaces in front of the code parts, or easier use the {} button after selecting/highlighting the code to format!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
for key, value in list.items():
  print("\033[31m{}\033[m".format(key)+ "\033[30m{}\033[m".format(value))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)

But if you are still going with this logic, here is the fix (you forgot to reset the colorings)

```py
Dictionary={}
for i in range(len(List)-1):
    Dictionary[i] = [List[i + 1][0]]
print("\033[31m{}\033[0m".format(Dictionary))
```

Comment: Isnt that the same code in the Question? I already put the fix version for my own problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: Compare the last line